# How do I speed up geopy calculations for a pandas DataFrame with approx. 100k entries?

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

I have a pandas DataFrame called "orders" with approx. **100k entries** containing address data (zip, city, country). For each entry, I would like to calculate the **distance** to a specific predefined address.

So far, I'm looping over the dataframe rows with a for-loop and using **geopy** to 1. **get latitude and longitude values** for each entry and 2. **calculate the distance** to my predefined address.

Although this works, it takes an awful lot of time (over 15 hours with an average of 2 iterations / second) and I assume that I haven't found the most efficient way yet. Although I did quite a lot of research and tried out different things like vectorization, these alternatives did not seem to speed up the process (maybe because I didn't implement them in the correct way, as I'm not a very experienced Python user).

This is my code so far:

```
def get_geographic_information():

    latitude = destination_geocode.latitude
    
    longitude = destination_geocode.longitude

    destination_coordinates = (latitude, longitude)

    distance = round(geopy.distance.distance(starting_point_coordinates, destination_coordinates).km, 2)
    
    return latitude, longitude, distance
```

```
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import geopy.distance

orders["Latitude"] = ""
orders["Longitude"] = ""
orders["Distance"] = ""

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="Project01")

starting_point = "my_address"
starting_point_geocode = geolocator.geocode(starting_point, timeout=10000)
starting_point_coordinates = (starting_point_geocode.latitude, starting_point_geocode.longitude)

for index in tqdm(range(len(orders))):
    destination_zip = orders.loc[index, "ZIP"]
    destination_city = orders.loc[index, "City"]
    destination_country = orders.loc[index, "Country"]
        
    destination = destination_zip + " " + destination_city + " " + destination_country
    destination_geocode = geolocator.geocode(destination, timeout=15000)
    
    if destination_geocode != None:
        geographic_information = get_geographic_information()
        
        orders.loc[index, "Latitude"] = geographic_information[0]
        
        orders.loc[index, "Longitude"] = geographic_information[1]
        
        orders.loc[index, "Distance"] = geographic_information[2]
    
    else:
        orders.loc[index, "Latitude"] = "-"
        
        orders.loc[index, "Longitude"] = "-"
        
        orders.loc[index, "Distance"] = "-"
```

From my previous research, I learned that the for-loop might be the problem, but I haven't managed to replace it yet. As this is my first question here, I'd appreciate any constructive feedback. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally, when code is really slow, it can be very insightful to measure which part of your code takes the most time. You can do this like this: `import time` and `t = time.time()` before your code `print(time.time() - t)` after your code.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I actually tried that before and learned that a single query only takes about 0.1 seconds to be executed. That's why I was looking for the mistake in my for-loop, but @gaw89's comment shows that the problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed of your script is likely limited by using Nominatim.  They throttle the speed to 1 request per second as per this link:

https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/

The only way to speed this script up would be to find a different service that allows bulk requests.  [Geopy has a list](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#geocoders) of geocoding services that it currently supports.  Your best bet would be to look through this list and see if you find a service that handles bulk requests (e.g. Google V3.  That would either allow you to make requests in batches or use a distributed process to speed things up.